# Single DB field, with multiple referencing, MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, data-integrity

I am currently structuring a DB, I need to have a field bed_types_id in my table.

This field has multiple options, EX. King, Queen, Two Queens, Two Doubles, etc.

If I make a field bed_types_id in my table that references the table bed_types by id, how do I reference more than one option.

EX: 1, 2, 3 would be King, Queen, OR Two Queens, as the bed types.

How should I do this properly with a relational database??

Comment: you normalize the design: pretty much anytime you have a field you want to store multiple individual/distinct data values in, you put it into a child table and establish a foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need another table with three columns:
id
room_id
bed_type_id

If a room has a king and a queen, this table would have two rows for that room.